# C# Overload method with var type

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am querying a SQL database via LINQ in my C# project and returning the data to a var type variable

How can I overload a method with var type?  example of what I am trying to do:

```
public decimal[][] method(var nameOfVar){}
```

If this cannot be done, what is an alternative?

Comment: If you want to not specify a type for that variable, you need to use generics.

Comment: Basic research would be good, you need to understand what var is. Also, your method is returning an array of arrays of decimals, it's not even trying to return a "var" type.

Answer (score 6):

> I am querying a SQL database via LINQ in my C# project and returning the data to a var type variable

The type of the variable isn't `var` - that's just the form of declaration you're using. The type of the variable is whatever the compiler infers it to be.

> How can I overload a method with var type?

You can't. `var` isn't a type.

Unfortunately, we don't know what you're trying to do in `method`. *Maybe* you want to make it a generic method. *Maybe* you want to make it take `object`. If you're actually trying to use an anonymous type, and pass values between methods, then you're probably best off creating a *named* type with the relevant properties.

Comment: This is more of the correct answer than mine. You should make your method generic, so that it will handle whatever type is passed in. That way, if changes to the LINQ query cause changes to the returned type, your method will still work.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is not a type. It is an indicator to perform type inference.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a type determined at compile-time. You should probably use `object` instead, if you want a generic input, or even better use genetics to specify the type when invoking the method.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "object" or "dynamic" which are both generic types that allow you to pass almost anything into the routine. As others have said, "var" by itself isn't a type but is replaced by the compiler with the actual type based on what you assign to that variable.

Comment: Is there a way in Visual Studio to perhaps break and find out what type var has chosen to use?  If I can find that, I'll be fine.  I just used var in the beginning because I didn't know which type to use for LINQ statements.

Comment: When you break in visual studio and mouse over a variable it will show you the type unless the object overrides "ToString" in which case it will show you a string representation of that object.

Your best bet, though is to read through the code and see where the object you pass into the routine comes from. If you posted this code it is possible someone might be able to help more as well.

Comment: Value: "{<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal,decimal,etc>[66]}".  It returns what looks like a catalog of information from SQL.  I sorting through the data returned in break requires going 5 - 15 layers/tabs deep.

Comment: I'm not sure what is in it, but LINQ is returning an anonymous type. For more information on those see "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx". You can just pass this into your routine as an object, then use reflection to get the property values. If this represents a real type you can also cast to that real type as well. More code might help in giving you a better answer.